# order by when using Constructor Expressions in JPA 2

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql, jpa-2.1

As a part of JSR-338 came the feature of using Constructor Expressions. 
The question is how I can use `order by` when using Constructor Expressions.

Given the example JPQL:

```
select com.acme.AggregatedInfo(
    c,
    (select status from Account where ssn = c.ssn)
)
from Customer c 
where m.id in (:customerIdList)
```

And the class AggregatedInfo

```
class AggregatedInfo {

    private final Customer customer;
    private final String status;

    public AggregatedInfo(Customer customer, String status) {...}

    // boilerplate javacode....
}
```

Im using this from a DAO like this:

```
public List<AggregatedInfo> getAggregatedResult(final List<Long> customerIdList)
    return em.createQuery(hql, AggregatedInfo.class)
        .setParameters("customerIdList", customerIdList)
        .getResultList();
}
```

If I want to order by the status - how can this be done via JPQL ?

I have tried the following without success:

```
select com.acme.AggregatedInfo(
    c,
    (select status from Account where ssn = c.ssn)
) as a
from Customers c 
where m.id in (:customerIdList)    
order by c.status
```

But this does not work.

Is it doable ? 
Please explain.

Comment: You are using JPA specific methods and classes or Hibernate?

Comment: I'm using the JPA api

Comment: Can you show me your DAO class?

Comment: I've added the dao code to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following. It worked for me with the similar implementation in Hibernate. It should work for you too

```
public List<AggregatedInfo> getAggregatedResult(final List<Long> customerIdList)
    return em.createNativeQuery(hql, AggregatedInfo.class)
        .setParameters("customerIdList", customerIdList)
        .getResultList();
}
```

Replace `entityManager.createQuery()` with `entityManager.createNativeQuery()`

Comment: Can i use `order by` when using native query ?

Comment: Yes you can, give it a try man. Hibernate is great implementation of JPA and it provides great features. It worked for me there, it should work for you here

Comment: @stalet **NativeQuery** term speaks for itself. U can pass plain SQL query as parameter to create JPA's `Query` object and to obtain `List`
I

Comment: It seems im getting a MappingException telling me that AggregatedInfo is not an entity. When using native queries i also have to add some mapping configurations... I will try rewriting the lots!

Comment: No issues, try replacing `em.createNativeQuery(hql, AggregatedInfo.class)` with `em.createNativeQuery(hql)`. The output will be same as you want.

If that didnt worked for you at the first place, try adding `@Entity` annotation on top of your `class AggregatedInfo`. Though i have no idea if JPA supports annotation. trying adding and then press **CTRL+ SHIFT+ I** tocken to let your IDE find proper package for it

Comment: Changing it to Entity doesnt work. But by adding a `@SqlResultSetMapping` with a `@ConstructorResult` however does fix the mapping problem. Then I used `em.createNativeQuery(hql, "mappingname")`. However with this solution i cannot write JPQL language type queries. I have to change to rewrite to plain sql and map the result in a resultsetmapper. It will solve the problem of sorting but without JPQL. So I am still looking for a way to use ordinary Query with JPQL and order the result.

Comment: If no-one comes around and have an answer with the use of createQuery - this is the accepted answer.